# API load testing in jmeter, while running for 100 users, 45 -50 users getting 200 reponse but remaining shows 500 internal server error

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

i tried with one API for 100 users. for 50 users I am getting success response but for remaining 50 I am getting 500 internal server error. how half of the API's alone getting failed. please suggest me a solution

Answer (score 0):

As per [500 Internal Server Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) description

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 500 Internal Server Error server error response code indicates **that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.**

So you need to look at your server logs to get the reason for failure. Most probably it becomes overloaded and cannot handle 100 users. Try [increasing the load gradually](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period) and inspect relationship between:

1. Number of users and number of requests per second
2. Number of users and response time

My expectation is that

- at the first phase of the test the response time will remain the same and the number of requests per second will grow proportionally to the number of users.
- at some stage you will see that the number of requests per second stops growing. The moment right before that is known as [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html).
- After that response time will start growing
- After that the errors will start occurring

You might want to collect and report the aforementioned metrics and indicate what is the current [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing). If you need to understand the reason - it's a whole big different story